# Deleting list of expression by rules

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list of expression:

```
 list = {(4 x^2)/135, (4 x^2 z)/135, -(4/15) PolyGamma[0, 7/15], 32/225 x PolyGamma[0, 7/15], 
 Sin[z], -((1652 x^2 PolyGamma[0, 76/45 + z])/30375), x Cos[z + 1]};
```

I'd like to delete  `z` symbol with in the expression like this:

```
Newlist={(4 x^2)/135, -(4/15) PolyGamma[0, 7/15], 32/225 x PolyGamma[0, 7/15]}
```

One way is:

```
Newlist=DeleteCases[list /. z -> ComplexInfinity, Infinity | Indeterminate | ComplexInfinity]
```

There are better or smarter methods to do this ?

Comment: `Select[list, FreeQ[z]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`FreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) to check for the existence of `z` in any of the expressions and filter using [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html):

```
Select[list, FreeQ[z]]
(* {(4 x^2)/135, -(4/15) PolyGamma[0, 7/15], 32/225 x PolyGamma[0, 7/15]} *)

Newlist == Select[list, FreeQ[z]]
(* True *)
```